# Tipsi stripe is not working with iOS and React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, stripe-payments

Here is the error message:

[image]

[image]

I checked this solution, but my paths already have that value in Xcode:

*[Build is failing in iOS #447](https://github.com/tipsi/tipsi-stripe/issues/447#issuecomment-493185096)*

Comment: The error messages ought to be posted as text (instead of images).

Comment: ok i will take care next time

Answer (score 1):

The `tipsi-stripe` library is no longer maintained or supported by the developers. You should instead use the official `stripe-react-native` library following the [migration guide](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-react-native/blob/master/docs/tipsi-stripe-migration-guide.md).